# Bootstrap 4 - container class and rounded corners?

Tags: bootstrap-4

How can I have achieve a div which has a container class from Bootstrap but also has rounded corners?

```
<div class="container rounded">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col">Approver:</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I use the above code, my corners still appear to be square however Bootstrap 4 documentation states that the "rounded" class should take care of rounded corners?

Comment: Shame that people upvote the answer so much and not the question.

Answer (score 11):

As per the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/#border-radius), The `rounded` class in bootstrap does the following:

```
.rounded {
    border-radius:.25rem!important
}
```

You should be able to use it on a container.

However, keep in mind that unless the background color is of a different color than the `container` (*or unless it has a differently colored border*), it won't be visible.

Here's a snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container rounded">
  This rounded container has no background color.
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container rounded bg-dark">
  This rounded container has a background color.
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container rounded" style="border:1px solid black">
  This rounded container has no background color, but it has a black border.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here trying to add rounded corners to a grid of images. For anyone doing the same:

```
<div class="img-rounded">
```

or

```
<img class="rounded" src="img.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `aspect-ratio` property:

```
aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio)